# Are references to functions in shared library required at start up, or not until actually used?

Tags: android, c, linker, shared-libraries

Note: This question is not about linking during compile time.

I'm asking this question because in Android we have to deal with different platform versions, and older platforms might be missing some libc functions.

Since most people (including me) builds against the latest platform SDK, we can always link against the most recent version of bionic libc, and the compilation can pass even if we reference something that will only be in a newer platform.

In Java it is typical to do something like:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    // Call new API.
} else {
    // Work around without the new API.
}
```

In this way even if the compiled bytecode contains reference to new API, it will execute fine on old API because that reference won't be reached.

So I was wondering if we can have something similar in C:

```c
if (android_get_device_api_level() >= __ANDROID_API_P__) {
    // Call new libc function.
} else {
    // Work around without the new function.
}
```

Will this work on an older platform even if a new function is referenced? i.e. Will Linux load the old libc for us despite missing some symbols, or will it be rejected on start up?

Comment: You are looking for “weak references.” (Sorry, I cannot provide details for Android.)